# Unable to achieve expected transaction in karate-gatling for load testing

Tags: performance, karate

We are using Karate-Gatling for performing load testing, with 4 API services

when we are running with minimal load i.e. 40 users (10 on each service) with 10 minutes duration and 10 seconds as pacing, we are able to achieve expected transaction.

But when we are trying to run with little more load i.e. 100 users (25 on each service) with 10 minutes duration and 10 seconds as pacing for each API service, we are not able to achieve expected transaction, even though the response times of each service is less than the applied pacing(10 sec), the number of transactions achieved is very much less than the expected.

we tried another load test with same number of users i.e. 100 users (25 on each service) with 10 minutes duration and 20 seconds as pacing for each API service, we almost achieved the expected transaction.

could you please let us know why the expected transactions are not achieved in 100 user tests with 10 sec as pacing.